# If statement that returns original function if false (similar to iferror, or substitute)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, conditional-statements

If I use IFERROR as opposed to IF(ISERROR I can save typing the condition twice.

i.e.

```
 =IFERROR(Long lookup,"not found")
```

is much preferable to

```
 =IF(ISERROR(long_lookup),"not found",long_lookup)
```

when there is a long formula involved.

However for something like

```
 =IF(long_lookup=some_condition,"outtext",long_lookup)
```

Is there a generic formula where I can type

```
 =IF2(long_lookup,some_condition,"outtext")
```

for things other than errors.  Or something similar, which allows me to output the original formula if a condition is not met (rather than simply outputting FALSE).

Essentially, I want to avoid an unnecessarily duplicated formula.

A workarround is to put the formula in the column before of course and just use

```
 =if(condition(a2),"out if true",A2))
```

But it's a pain

EDIT: also similar is =SUBSTITUTE(), but this doesn't work if the whole cell you're trying to replace is also contained as a substring of other cells, e.g. if I wanted a lookup returning "B" to output "foobar" but there was a possibility of returning "Batch 1".  This also does not work for blanks.

Comment: This is very broad. There are all kinds of workarounds for all kinds of situations, so unless you have a specific example, it's hard to give an answer.

Comment: Now I've edited my question I suggest you clean up your comments, as I have

Comment: [Here are some examples from a SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22359452/if-function-is-there-a-way-to-avoid-repeating-formula) - not much you haven't already mentioned, but a few ideas.

Comment: Here's [an article](http://excelribbon.tips.net/T008264_Leaving_a_Cell_Value_Unchanged_If_a_Condition_Is_False.html) that speaks to this problem, but requires VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's a very good question I'd also use frequently, but unfortunately currently I don't think there would be a general solution you could use.

One workaround would be to use VBA function, but it's also have it's own limitations, below you can find a short function to do it (of course if you want to use it broadly it need to be improved e.g. error handling, adapt to more operator, not only `=`):

```
Function IfCondition(expression as Variant, criteria as Variant, ElseExpression)
  IF expression = criteria Then
    IfCondition = expression
  Else
    IfCondition = elseExpression
  End If
End Function
```